# How to inactivate all items in the botnav component of Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify botnav; each item is activated under a certain router path, I want to inactivate the item when it's under another path.

I tried to set `active.sync` to -1 when I want to inactivate the tab, this will work if I never activate any item in the botnav, but if I activate an item, then set active.sync=-1 again, it will automatically activate the first item:

```
 <v-bottom-nav
  :active.sync="bottomNav"
  :value="true"
  shift
  absolute
>
  <v-btn
    color="teal"
    flat
    value="recent"
  >
    <span>Recent</span>
    <v-icon>history</v-icon>
  </v-btn>

  <v-btn
    color="teal"
    flat
    value="favorites"
  >
    <span>Favorites</span>
    <v-icon>favorite</v-icon>
  </v-btn>

  <v-btn
    color="teal"
    flat
    value="nearby"
  >
    <span>Nearby</span>
    <v-icon>place</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-bottom-nav>
```

In the script:

```
 watch:{
 $route:function(to, from){
 switch(to.path){
  case "/0": 
    this.bottomNav=0;
  break
  case "/1": 
    this.bottomNav=1;
  break
  case "/2": 
    this.bottomNav=2;
  break
  default: this.bottomNav=-1
  }
}
}
```

I did find a solution that works, by setting a dummy hidden item in the botnav and set the v-show of this item to false, when I want to inactivate all items, I activate this unshown one, and it result in what I want:

A dummy item:

```
<v-bottom-nav
 :active.sync="bottomNav"
 //more stuff
 >
//other items
<v-btn v-show="0" value="inactivate"></v-btn>
</v-bottom-nav>
```

And do this whenever I want to inactivate all items in the script:

```
this.bottomNav = "inactivate"
```

This WORKS, but that's kind of hacky, is there a more formal/elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for `active.sync` is undefined, so try using [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) to reset:

```
this.bottomNav = void(0)
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/e8a67qtp/ ]